# IE9 Can't Find DOM Element Appropriately

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML table with a `<tfoot>` that I am trying to dynamically update. In Firefox this script executes fine:

```
 dataTableFooter = document.getElementById('dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tfoot');
 dataTableFooter[0].innerHTML = "This is the footer";
```

However in IE the following error is returned:

```
SCRIPT600: Invalid target element for this operation.
```

Navigating the DOM in FF:

[image]

And in IE - we can see the structure of the elements is created differently, so `dataTableFooter[0].innerHTML`  would be invalid:

[image]

I can't assign an id to my table footer as it is generated via the Alloy UI framework and is always randomized, otherwise this wouldn't be an issue - any cross-browser solutions on how this `<tfoot>` element can be retrieved and the `innerHTML` set?

Update: This is a problem in IE9 and under specifically

Comment: Try jQuery to iron out these inconsistencies in browsers behavior esp. < IE10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're targeting IE9, because this is not a problem in IE10+.

In IE9, you can clear the tfoot's `innerHTML`, but you cannot set it.  You can, however, create a new element, and append it as a child:

```
var dataTableFooter= document.getElementById('dataTable').getElementsByTagName('tfoot');

var div= document.createElement('td');
div.innerHTML= 'This is the footer';
dataTableFooter[0].innerHTML= '';
dataTableFooter[0].appendChild(div);
```

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L444ww2p/)

Comment: Thanks Rick, this method works in both IE9 and FF - do you have any reference on this issue?

Comment: I'm not finding anything official, but it's come up on stackoverflow before:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148406/ie-invalid-target-element-appending-table-using-innerhtml-string